# SE site for household appliance questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, site-proposal

Is there currently a Stack Exchange site where I can ask about household appliances?

In the current case, my question is whether it's good practice to turn off a fridge when you don't need it, and if yes, in what intervals.

Is there a site (or proposal) where this question would fit in? It's not Food and Cooking, and it's probably not Home Improvement, either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *not* currently a household appliance Stack Exchange site.

The latest list of sites can be found here: [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress)

If you *want* an appliance site, support it here: [Area 51: Home Appliances](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/8718/home-appliances)

Comment: Cheers Robert, I didn't find that one.

Comment: The proposal for Home Appliances has since been removed.

Answer (score 8):

[**Home Improvement** or **DIY**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) has many [appliance questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appliances). Of the [12 most popular](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appliances?sort=votes&pageSize=15), fewer than half are about operating:

- 5 operating questions
- 5 installing questions
- 2 repairing questions

That's plenty. So go ahead and post an appliance question there. In 2019 there are [368 questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refrigerator) about refrigerators.